# Unable to create actions different from index

Tags: zend-framework

When I create a view different from index action (for example the action video/add) the page is without css and layout. For index action is everything ok. Any helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check the  tag on your page. Sounds like your css paths are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using a layout so the css path is the same for 'index' and 'add' action. The 'video/index' page is ok, the 'video/add' isn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you use pretty urls? Then it's better to use absolute url's. That way the path is allways correct.